# How do I rerender a component from another competent

Tags: reactjs, react-context

I have an `ActivityFeed` of posts. When I click on an icon in the `ActivityPost` component it saves the postId in a global state (`EditPostIndex`) that's meant to act like a toggle for the `CreatePost` and `EditPost` component in the Activity feed. When I click on the `editpost` icon it brings up the body of the post that I'm suppose to  edit

**ActivityFeed**

```
const ActivityFeed = () => {
    const {posts} = useContext(GlobalContext);
    const {editPostIndex} = useContext(GlobalContext);
    return (
        <div id="mobile-activity">
            <DeviceNav />
            { editPostIndex === null ? 
                <CreatePost />
            :
                <EditPost />
            }
            {posts.slice(0).reverse().map(post => (
                <ActivityPost key={post.id} post={post} /> 
            ))}     
        </div>
    )
}
```

**ActivityPost**

```
function ActivityPost({post, index}) => {
    const {toggleEditPost} = useContext(GlobalContext);
    function updatePost(index){
        toggleEditPost(index)
    }
}
```

**EditPost.js**

```
const EditPost = () => {
    const {posts} = useContext(GlobalContext);
    const {updatePost} = useContext(GlobalContext);
    const {editPostIndex} = useContext(GlobalContext);
    let val = posts[editPostIndex].body;
    let [body, setBody] = useState(val);

    function editPost() {
        //update
    }
    return (
        <div  id="make-post">
            <div id="create-post">
                <textarea value={body} onChange={(e) => setBody(e.target.value)} id="post-activity" placeholder="Tell them what you think."></textarea>
            </div>
            <div id="create-post-actions">
            
                <button onClick={editPost} id="post">Edit</button>
            
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}
```

**GlobalState/GlobalContext**

```
const initialState = {
    posts: posts,
    editPostIndex: null
}

export const GlobalProvider = ({children}) => {
    const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(AppReducer, initialState)

    function toggleEditPost(index = null){
        dispatch({
            type: 'TOGGLE_EDIT_POST',
            payload: index
        })
        //alert(index);
    }
    function updatePost(post){
        dispatch({
            type: 'UPDATE_POST',
            payload: post
        })
        toggleEditPost(null);
    }
}
```

The problem is that in `EditPost` component `let val = posts[editPostIndex].body; let [body, setBody] = useState(val);` the useState only renders once because the `EditPostIndex` is already changed. How do I make it so when I click on the edit post icon the `let [body, setBody] = useState(val);` changes to the posts body that I want to edit? Or rerender the `EditPost` component so setBody is set again?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case, I'd say you'd need more hooks like `useState` & `useEffect` to detect a change in your context EditPost.js.

```
const [postIndex, setPostIndex] = useState(editPostIndex);
useEffect(() => {
   if(editPostIndex !== postIndex){
      setPostIndex(editPostIndex);
      setBody(posts[editPostIndex].body)
   }
}, [setPostIndex, postIndex])
```

Comment: `[setPostIndex, postIndex]` it doesn't work with and rerenders every time. I don't yet see the problem with this because I'm new to react, but maybe you will. Other than that this is the answer that works

Comment: These are dependency values of the effect where we set the edit index of the EditPost. This means the effect gets called after every render once there's some change on our dependency values. I might have missed other dependencies with that list`, [setPostIndex, postIndex, editPostIndex, setBody]`. However, with the problem on re-rendering, I really can't tell just on eye test right now.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [redux](https://redux.js.org/), which is actually built for this purpose. With redux you can subscribe components to the redux store and then push updates which will automatically update the subscribed components.